Are doubly-linked structures allowed?
I am writing a package with an S4 class that looks like a simple tree structure: the class, say S4node, has a slot nodes which is a list of child S4node (via a common virtual ancestor, say S4base). The class also has a slot parent of type S4base that links back up to the parent of the child nodes. That looks more-or-less like this (with barebones coding for clarity):
# Create the root node, slot parent is set to NA, slot id is set to 567
> root <- new_node(567) 

# Create some child nodes, slot parent is set to root, slot nodes has new node added
> root <- add_node(root, 5671)
> root <- add_node(root, 5672)

This works ok and all slots are set correctly. Traversing down the hierarchy works, as well as traversing up the hierarchy. But here is the problem: when I want to traverse up the hierarchy the nodes slot is set to NULL, which becomes obvious when traveling down some other branch. Like this:
> node5671 <- find_node(root, 5671)

# Now traverse 5671 -> 567 -> 5672
> node5672 <- node_travel(node5671, "../5672")
Error: path not found

On the console this becomes clearer:
> length(root@nodes)
[1] 2
> node5671@parent@id
[1] 567
> nodes5671@parent@nodes
NULL

# Best one yet: take the root node, get a child, get the parent (= root), get the nodes = NULL!!!
> root@nodes[[1]]@parent@nodes
NULL

It appears to me that the list with nodes is emptied automatically, but only when implicitly accessed: I can construct the list in the first place, only when referencing the list through a @parent lookup is the list emptied. Is this to avoid endless recursion? Is it a quirk of gc()? Is there a work-around for this?

What the node_travel function does?

It looks also that it might be a problem of copy/reference. This case I guess you need reference semantic and a node is a reference to a data structure. You could use environments, RefClass or R6 instead of S4.

@nicola But all I have here is references, I am not modifying any part of the tree structure so there should be no copying, only creating another binding to the existing tree structure. I'll look into your suggestions on environments. RC and R6 would require a complete refactoring of my code so I hope I can avoid that.

What do you mean that you have references? Without seeing the implementation of your class, it's difficult to say anything

@nicola When I say "references" I meant that I am binding a name to an object. I am not modifying anything so there should be no copying of the object taking place.

Not clear what you mean. Is there a reason why you don't want to share the implementation? As stated, there is no way to answer this question. You should provide a reproducible example.

@nicola Not sharing is not an issue, the entire code base is on GitHub (https://github.com/pvanlaake/ncdfCF) except for this bit because it is not working... An MRE with S4 classes is unworkable as you'd have to load, build and install multiple files to get a workable example. Hence why I provide a mockup to demonstrate the issue.

Are you aware of the ncdf4 package? Here the link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf4/index.html. However, the point is the implementation, so you could show how you defined this S4node class and the function you used. Otherwise how one could help?

I think I would try to use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pointr/ to implement the linked list idea; or step out of the language and do some rcpp type stuff.

@Patrick You don’t have any references here since R uses value semantics and copying, not reference semantics (except for environments).

@NirGraham Jesus, what is that?! This… apologies for the choice of word, but, really: abomination… is absolutely not necessary to implement reference semantics in R.

@NirGraham That package triggered me so much that I wrote my own, to show how to implement this properly: https://cran.r-project.org/package=aka — mind, using ‘aka’ would still not be appropriate here (or indeed for most purposes that ‘pointr’ ineptly claims to address).

I can only assume that add_node modifies the nodes slot of a copy of its argument and returns the modified copy.  The copy gets a new node and the original is preserved.  It was not too hard to devise an example using tracemem ...
> setClass("S4base")
> setClass("S4root",
+          contains = "S4base",
+          slots = c(id = "integer", parent = "NULL", nodes = "list"),
+          prototype = list(id = 0L, parent = NULL, nodes = list()))
> setClass("S4node",
+          contains = "S4base",
+          slots = c(id = "integer", parent = "S4base", nodes = "list"),
+          prototype = list(id = 1L, parent = new("S4root"), nodes = list()))
> 
> root <- new("S4root", id = 0L); tracemem(root)
[1] "<0x1370506d8>"
> node <- new("S4node", id = 1L, parent = root)
> root@nodes <- list(node)
tracemem[0x1370506d8 -> 0x1370f5aa8]: 
> identical(root, root@nodes[[1L]]@parent)
[1] FALSE
> 
> str(root)
Formal class 'S4root' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
  ..@ id    : int 0
  ..@ parent: NULL
  ..@ nodes :List of 1
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'S4node' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ id    : int 1
  .. .. .. ..@ parent:Formal class 'S4root' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ id    : int 0
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ parent: NULL
  .. .. .. .. .. ..@ nodes : list()
  .. .. .. ..@ nodes : list()
>

To get around copy-on-modify in R, you should probably use environments (possibly S4 classes extending environment):
> root <- new.env(parent = emptyenv()); try(tracemem(root))
Error in tracemem(root) : 
  'tracemem' is not useful for promise and environment objects
> node <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
> 
> root$id <- 0L
> root$nodes <- list(node)
> 
> node$id <- 1L
> node$nodes <- list()
> node$parent <- root
> 
> identical(root, root$nodes[[1L]]$parent)
[1] TRUE
> 


Oh wow, this is really surprising! Modifying a slot in an instance of the class gets you a whole new instance! I suppose it makes sense, the new slot value changes the instance after all, but still surprising since it makes S4 really inefficient in these types of class hierarchies. Answer accepted and +1 for an excellent explanation and demonstration.

Using an environment to solve this issue means that I am R6-ifying my classes. Maybe time to rebase my code after all...

root is copied only because it is referenced by node when you try to modify it.  The copy would not occur if root were unreferenced.  I suspect that you can implement this is S4 if you ensure that S4base extends the basic class environment.  There is an example in help("setClass").
